# Lombok @Accessor and JPA Beans

Tags: java, lombok

I am using Lombok to generate getters and setters for my JPA entities. However, I also very much like the Syntax that is provided by the `@Accessor(fluent = true, chain = true)`. But this is not compatible with JPA, which requires the signature `void setProperty()` which prevents chaining.

Is it possible to use both "regular" getters and setters and fluent accessors at the same time with Lombok?

Answer (score 2):

A few months late, but this is for anyone that lands here after asking google about lombok's accessors being experimental. For your chaining requirements, you can use:

```
@With
@Getter
@Setter
```

This will give you regular setters and getters and will give you "With" methods that are chainable.

NB @With requires:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. From [the docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors)

> The `@Accessors` annotation is used to configure **how** lombok
> generates and looks for getters, setters, and with-ers.

Emphasis mine.

`@Accessors` can configure *how* a method is generated, but not *how many* methods are generated.

Technically it's still an experimental feature so that could change in the future. However, I don't see any current intention to support that. You are doubling the API footprint of the class to have slightly different syntax; not really worth it, in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, but what I need is both fluent and non-fluent at the same time. So I would need `getFoo()` and `foo()`.